# Sharing the same page Title on all Pages in Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin Forms. I have a Page 1, Page 2 in the MasterDetail Pages.

I need to share the same title in both the pages. How should i achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom BasePage that inherits from ContentPage.  Set the title in that custom class.  Then have all your other pages inherit from the custom base page.

```
public class MyBasePage : ContentPage {

  public MyBasePage() : base() {

    this.Title = "My Title";
  }
}
```